# InputMismatch exception reading boolean values

Tags: java, inputmismatchexception

I have a file with some values in it:

```
11
8
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0
```

I need to read those values into a 2D `ArrayList`. The fist two values (11 and 8) would be the number of rows and columns respectively. So here is the code:

```
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

            int x, y;

            x = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println(x + " has been read");

            y = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println(y + " has been read");


            ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>> pixelMap;
            pixelMap = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>>();
            ArrayList<Boolean> buffer_line = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

            Boolean buffer;


            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < y; j++){
                    buffer = scanner.nextBoolean();
                    System.out.println(buffer + " has been read");
                    //buffer_line.add(buffer);
                }
                //pixelMap.add(buffer_line);
                //buffer_line.clear();
            }
```

The problem is - the program reads first two numbers successfully, and when it comes to boolean values, it throws InputMismatch exception on line

```
buffer = scanner.nextBoolean();
```

so I can't undersand why. `0` should be read next and it is boolean - so what's actually mismatching?

I also point out that if change `buffer` type to integer and then assign `scanner.nextInt()`, the program would read all the values properly, so in the output I would see all of them. So then of course, I can change `ArrayList`  to Integer to make that work, but it would be semantically wrong as it would hold only boolean values. 
Can anyone help me to find out the problem?

Comment: In Java `boolean` does not have a numeric representation.

Comment: Boolean values are true/false. 1 and 0 are int values.

Comment: Oh...that was quite unexpected, as I've got used to 0/1 representation in C++. So, what would be the best solution? Read the entire file as integers and then convert to boolean, or something else?

Comment: @Tony you could just do `buffer = scanner.nextInt()>0?true:false;`. Also FYI using `buffer_line.clear()` will clear out all the buffers in your `pixelMap` because you never created a new object (they are all the same ArrayList). Upon making a new line make your `buffer_line` a new Object `buffer_line = new ArrayList<Boolean>();`

Comment: @ug_ thank you so much. I've just forgot that there is no copy constructor in Java unlike C++. Need some time to think over my programming logic. :)

Comment: @Tony Dont forget with Java to take advantage of the great IDE support. Most IDEs support hovering to show java documentation or `ctrl+right click` to navigate into methods so you can look at their source. Using these to your advantage can save alot of time and help resolve issues much faster :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have this statement:

> buffer = scanner.nextBoolean();

But I do not see `boolean` values `true` or `false` in the input file.

In Java, 0 and 1 are not treated as boolean values like in other languages such as C.

You need to read these values as `int` and then manually map them to `boolean` values.

Logic something like this:

```
int val = scanner.nextInt();
boolean buffer = (val == 1) ? true : false;
```